# How to use Azure Managed Identity to access Azure Cosmos db on ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, azure-cosmosdb, mongoid, azure-managed-identity

I have a ruby on rails application. I am using `mongoid` gem to connect to ***Azure cosmos db for mongo*** service on azure. Currently, I use username and password for authentication. Instead of using username and password for authentication, I want to use Azure Managed Identity.

In `config/mongoid.yml` file, following is the configuration

```yaml
      options:
        user: <%= ENV['USERNAME'] %>
        password: <%= ENV['PASSWORD'] %>
        ssl: true
        auth_source: admin
```

Also, documentation of mongoid says, qouting the documentation here:-

> Change the default authentication mechanism. Valid options are: :scram,
> :mongodb_cr, :mongodb_x509, and :plain. Note that all authentication
> mechanisms require **username and password**, with the exception of :mongodb_x509.
> Default on mongoDB 3.0 is :scram, default on 2.4 and 2.6 is :plain.

I have gone through the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-vm-managed-identities-cosmos?tabs=azure-portal), where they have used AzureIdentity library for .Net, Java, Javascript to authenticate using MI. I am looking for the same for ruby on rails.

Could anyone please help/guide me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Cosmos DB for Mongo DB(Both vCore and RU mode) do not support Managed Identity. The documentation that you're seeing is applicable to Cosmos DB NOSQL API only.